# Slave settings not working

Tags: mysql, replication

I have this machine as slave. Below is the command I ran and stuck. I done the change on the config file and set the id=2 too. Anything else I am missing here?

```
slave start; 
ERROR 1201 (HY000): Could not initialize master info structure; more error messages can be found in the MySQL error log 
mysql> change master to MASTER_HOST='192.168.1.15', MASTER_USER='replication1', MASTER_PASSWORD='*******',MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001'; ERROR 1201 (HY000): Could not initialize master info structure; more error messages can be found in the MySQL error log ?
```

Below is the results of

```
show master status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            File: mysql-bin.000001
        Position: 98
    Binlog_Do_DB: fms,sms
Binlog_Ignore_DB:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.1.15
                  Master_User: replication1
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 98
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 243
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: fms
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 98
              Relay_Log_Space: 399
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you did not specify the MASTER_LOG_POS in the CHANGE MASTER TO command.

Another problem could be this:

When you set up MySQL Replication, you have to explicitly set this in /etc/my.cnf

on the master:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=1
```

and this on the Slave

```
[mysqld]
server-id=2
```

Then CHANGE MASTER TO can work

Since the Master is MySQL 5.0.67 and you loaded the same data into the Slave, here is the CHANGE MASTER TO command you need:

```
change master to
MASTER_HOST='192.168.1.15',
MASTER_USER='replication1',
MASTER_PASSWORD='*******',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
MASTER_LOG_POS=98;
```

Here is something you need to know fot setting up other slaves

- The Master must be the same version as the Slave or older.
- The starting position for any empty Master is

  - 107 for MySQL 5.5
  - 106 for MySQL 5.1
  - 98 before MySQL 5.1

Now you have replication working, take note of the following

- Relay_Log_Space is 399
- Exec_Master_Log_Pos is 98

Do the following:

- Run this command on the Master: `CREATE DATABASE rolando;`
- Do `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` on the Slave
- Do `SHOW DATABASES;` on the Slave

What results should you have?

- Relay_Log_Space should be greater than 399
- Exec_Master_Log_Pos should be greater than 98
- The database `rolando` should appear in the `SHOW DATABASES;` on the Slave

If this happens, congratulations !!! Replication is working !!!

From here, you just have to monitor

- Slave_IO_Running (make sure it is Yes)
- Slave_SQL_Running (make sure it is Yes)
- Seconds_Behind_Master (should be zero, long running queries make it increase until all queries are processed)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64621/discussion-on-answer-by-rolandomysqldba-slave-settings-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

Try this possible solutions:

- delete relay bin file and try

> stop slave; CHANGE MASTER TO
>          master_log_file='name_of_current_file_on_master',master_log_pos=4;
>          start slave;
>
> ```
>    it will download play again the file
> ```

- just stop your slave by :

> STOP SLAVE; then use command to reset your slave:
>
> ```
>        CHANGE MASTER TO master_host= 'master_ip or
>        hostname',master_user='username eg
>        :root'master_log_file='bin.021',master_log_pos=275410644;
>
>        NOTE where master_log_file tells you about the log file of your
>        master and the master_log_pos tells about the position from where to
>        start the replication .you can get these details by running this
>        command on your master:
>
>        show master status\G;
>        *************************** 1. row *************************** File:bin.021 Position: 275410644 Binlog_Do_DB: Binlog_Ignore_DB: 1
>        row in set (0.03 sec)
>
>        then start your slave once again by :
>
>        START SLAVE: then go for SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
>
>    make sure SLAVE_IO_RUNNING and SLAVE_SQL_RUNNING is set to YES
> ```